# Expectation of $\frac{1}{1+X}$ for Gamma

Tags: probability-distributions, expectation

I am trying to evaluate the following integral:

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{c+x} \frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} x^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta x} dx $$

I have tried simple transformation and by-parts and nothing worked. Then I found this simple solution on internet at  http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=655393 :

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{c+x} \frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} x^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta x} dx = \beta^{\alpha} c^{\alpha-1} e^{\beta c}\Gamma(1-\alpha, \beta c) $$

It would be great if someone could verify if this is indeed the answer. I don't know Maple or any other software that can evaluate integrals and hence there is no way to verify the correctness. Any reference (paper,book) would be great too.

I am a Bayesian Statistician and I need this for evaluating a posterior quantity.

Comment: The term $\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}$ doesn't depend on $x$, you could take it out of the integral.

Comment: Mathematica confirms the result. Notice that $\frac{b^a}{\Gamma(a)}$ is a constant that does not depend on *x*, and $\int_0^\infty x^{a-1}e^{-x}dx=\Gamma(a)$ - See [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: Yes, I can, but, I kept it so that the integral becomes expectation of 1/(1+x) where x follows a gamma distribution with parameters alpha, beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $\displaystyle\frac1{c+x}=\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-(c+x)t}\mathrm dt$ and interchange the order of the integrals. This yields that the integral you wish to compute is
$$
I=\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-ct}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} x^{\alpha-1}\mathrm e^{-(\beta+t) x} \mathrm dx\mathrm dt=\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-ct}\frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{(\beta+t)^{\alpha}}\mathrm dt.
$$
The change of variable $s=c(\beta+t)$ yields
$$
I=\mathrm e^{c\beta}\beta^{\alpha}c^{1-\alpha}\int_{c\beta}^\infty s^{-\alpha}\mathrm e^{-s}\mathrm ds=\mathrm e^{c\beta}\beta^{\alpha}c^{1-\alpha}\Gamma(1-\alpha, \beta c). $$

Comment: Knowledge of the theory of Laplace transforms always helps ;)

Comment: Awesome .. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$\ds{{\cal J}\pars{\alpha, \beta, c} \equiv \int_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over c + x}\,
{\beta^{\alpha} \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha}}\,x^{\alpha - 1}\expo{-\beta x}\,\dd x
= {\beta^{\alpha} \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha}}\,{\cal K}\pars{\alpha, \beta, c}}\tag{1}$

> \begin{align}
> &\mbox{where}\\
> {\cal K}\pars{\alpha, \beta, c}
> & \equiv \int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\alpha - 1}\expo{-\beta x} \over c + x}\,\dd x
> =
> \beta^{1 - \alpha}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\pars{\beta x}^{\alpha - 1}\expo{-\beta x} \over \beta x + \beta c}\,\dd\pars{\beta x}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \beta^{1 - \alpha}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{-\pars{1 - \alpha}}\expo{-x} \over x + \beta c}\,\dd x
> =
> \beta^{1 - \alpha}\,
> {\Gamma\pars{1 - \bracks{1 - \alpha}}\Gamma\pars{1 - \alpha,\beta c}
> \over
> \expo{-\beta c}\pars{\beta c}^{\alpha}}
> \\&\mbox{See G&R}\ {\bf 8.353}.3\,,\quad 7^{\underline{\rm a}}\ \mbox{ed. Page 900}. \\&\mbox{The result is valid whenever}\ \Re\alpha >0\ \mbox{and}\ \beta, c > 0.
> \\[3mm]
> {\cal K}\pars{a,b,c} &= \beta^{1 - 2\alpha}c^{-\alpha}\expo{\beta c}
> \Gamma\pars{\alpha}\Gamma\pars{1 - \alpha,\beta c}
> \end{align}

By replacing this result in $\pars{1}$, we found:
$$
\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\alpha - 1}\expo{-\beta x} \over c + x}\,\dd x
=
\beta^{1 - \alpha}c^{-\alpha}\expo{\beta c}\Gamma\pars{1 - \alpha,\beta c}}
$$
Notice that it's slightly different of the OP proposed answer.

Comment: The blue formula equates some quantities with different dimensions.